# How to add custom checkbox with event in customer registration Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, custom-field, checkbox

> I'm working on creating a custom checkbox with an event

```
<div class="field tcagreecreateaccount required">
    <div class="control">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tcagreecreateaccount" name="tcagreecreateaccount" data-validate="{required:false}" class="input-checkbox checkbox required" value="1">
        <label for="tcagreecreateaccount" class="label">
            <?= __('Custom checkbox') ?>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

> 1)**when the checkbox is ticked need to show 
>   extra two fields in customer registration**
>
> 2)How I change the checkbox as optional one

How I can do it ???
Any ideas?

Edit 1:

addtional.phtml

```
<div id="idofyourinputwrapper">
    <div class="field skype required">
        <label class="label" for="skype2">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Check now')) ?></span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="skype2" id="skype22" value="" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Check now')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:false}">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: hm wait..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Replace this

```
<div class="field tcagreecreateaccount required">
<div class="control">
    <input type="checkbox" id="tcagreecreateaccount" name="tcagreecreateaccount" data-validate="{required:false}" class="input-checkbox checkbox required" value="1">
    <label for="tcagreecreateaccount" class="label">
        <?= __('Custom checkbox') ?>
    </label>
</div>
</div>
```

with this

```
<div class="field tcagreecreateaccount">
<div class="control">
    <input type="checkbox" id="tcagreecreateaccount" name="tcagreecreateaccount" class="input-checkbox checkbox" value="1">
    <label for="tcagreecreateaccount" class="label">
        <?= __('Custom checkbox') ?>
    </label>
</div>
</div>
```

then add the below script in your phtml

```
require(['jquery'],function($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
var ckbox = $('#tcagreecreateaccount');
$('#tcagreecreateaccount').on('click',function () {
    if (ckbox.is(':checked')) {
        $('#idofyourinputwrapper').show(); //idofyourinputwrapper is your input wrapper
    } else {
        $('#idofyourinputwrapper').hide();
    }
});
});
});
```

wrap your two inputs with a **div** like below.

```
<div id="idofyourinputwrapper">
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i tried but not event working....

Comment: Event?? what that mean? The above code do, remove required field and when you click checkbox it will show and hide the below field. Please update your code

Comment: i added this   not working   <div id="idofyourinputwrapper">
    <div class="field skype required">
        <label class="label" for="skype2">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Check now')) ?></span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="skype2" id="skype22" value="" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Check now')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:false}">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

Comment: i set is required:false

Comment: Have you added script ??

Comment: I tried it and it's working and given answer after worked? FYI

Comment: yes   i added  the script

Comment: FYI   means.....///

Comment: Update your code @prabhakaran7

Comment: but the js code showing in inpect

Comment: i updated the code with edit1

Comment: check console for any errors and make sure you've done everything I've given in answer

Comment: Error: Script error for: fancybox http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterro

Comment: updated the answer there was a script error, please check it

Comment: Add this updated script @prabhakaran7

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove required from your checkbox and other two attributes.

Both attributes depending on checkbox click will be hidden by default (can do with CSS or JS).

On checkbox click, you can use jQuery to display both attributes.

Comment: done.........................